# json Array to bean ( object mapper )

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, spring-boot-maven-plugin

Read the json object and store into the bean by creating the new getter n setter. I want to read the bold value from below json object received as string.

```
[{"country":"**India**","provinces":[{**"province":"India","confirmed":265928,"recovered":129095,"deaths":7473,"active":129360**}],"latitude":20.593684,"longitude":78.96288,"date":"2020-06-08"}]
```

Bean:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CoronaBean {
private String country; } and other needs to be created
```

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            CoronaBean[] coronaBean = mapper.readValue(json, CoronaBean[].class);
            for(CoronaBean c: coronaBean ){
            System.out.println(c.getCountry());
            }
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I am successfully able to read the country but I want to read other values which are in bold above

Answer (score 1):

`CoronaBean` should contain property `provinces`, which must be another Bean with properties you want from there. Simple as that.

Look at the code:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CoronaBean {
private String country; 
private ProvinceBean[] provinces
...getters and setters

} 

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ProvinceBean {
private Integer confirmed;
private Integer recovered;
...rest you want and getters and setters
```

I think you can also check this question for more details and ways to achive what you need:
[How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)